# Как вывести то, что ввел пользователь?

Tags: c

Пользователь вводит число. Вывести всего цифры этого числа, каждое с новой строки. Пример

> 432567
>   4
>   3
>   2
>   5
>   6

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int A,i;

    printf("Vvod chisla A\n");

    scanf("\n%d",&A);

    printf("%d\n",A);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 int A,i;

 printf("Vvod chisla A\n");

 scanf("\n%d",&A);

 

 return 0;

Comment: Сразу видно тех кто пользуется ms vc++ :)

Comment: Как можно вывести каждое число с новой строки?

Comment: Перевод строки \n в вашем коде он есть.

Comment: просто я ввожу число , нажимаю Enter , и программа вылетает

Comment: Ну да, вы читаете число как-то странно.

Comment: У вас же кода, который бы вообще что-то выводил, нет в программе. Что вы от нее ожидаете?

Comment: я добавил строку вывода.но выводит тоже самое число . не пойму , как вывести каждую цифру с новой строки

Comment: @СтепанКотов вам стоит отредактировать вопрос и внести из него коди и замечания из комментариев

Answer (score 1):

Следующий участок кода выводит цифры целого числа в обратном порядке, начиная с последней цифры:

```
int digit = 0;
while (number >= 1) {
    // записываем в переменную последнюю цифру числа (остаток от деления на 10)
    digit = number % 10;
    // выводим цифру на экран
    printf("%d\t", digit); 
    // делим число на 10, чтобы избавиться от последней цифры
    number = number / 10; 
}
```

Вам осталось придумать, как вывести их в нужном Вам порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например,

```
printf("%d\n",A);
```

заменить на

```
char buf[40], *с;
sprintf(buf,"%d",A);
for(с = buf; *c; ++c)
    printf("%c\n",*c);
```

О безопасности, эффективности и т.п. *мне* можно не рассказывать :)

**Update**
Поскольку мне сказали, что это *слишком* сложно - вот еще вариант:

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    printf("Vvedite chislo A: ");
    for(c = getchar(); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = getchar())
    {
        putchar(c);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

**:)**

Comment: Сложновато для новичка, который едва-едва число вывел, не находите? :)

Comment: @SleepyPanda Нет, не нахожу. Предложите проще - с использованием стека, например :) Или с рекурсией. Как по мне - то я привел САМЫЙ простой метод. Еще проще - только ввод числа не как числа, а в виде строки и работа непосредственно с введенными символами.